# Flag all rows in a group using data table in R if some rows meet a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a data table (works much quicker to handle all the records I've got) and I want to flag rows depending on a condition met by some rows for a group. I'll try to illustrate. My data looks like the following:

```
ID  DATE    EVENT
1   01-Jan-97   A
1   01-Jan-97   K
2   03-Jan-03   A
3   04-Jan-03   K
```

So there is an ID, a date and an event. The ultimate objective is to delete the rows that have EVENT=A if there is already an EVENT=K for the same date. So I thought about setting two flags, one if the group (ID,DATE) has A and other if they have K, so then, if it has both flags=1, I would delete the row containing A cause I wouldn't need it.

So, getting the first two flags it's ok. This is how the code looks like:

```
mydata.table[EVENT=="K", k.flag:=1, by=.(ID, DATE)]
```

I do the same for the A.flag. Then I don't know exactly how to get a third flag to mark that if it has both then I can delete the record with A. So I want a table something like:

```
ID  DATE    EVENT   K.FLAG  A.FLAG  BOTH
1   01-Jan-97   A      0       1    1
1   01-Jan-97   K      1       0    1
2   03-Jan-03   A      0       1    0
3   04-Jan-03   K      1       0    0
```

Then I would just delete for both=1 and EVENT=A. I know it's not a very elegant solution but it's the best one I can come up with but I'm having problems with the statement for the third flag. Any suggestions? I assume that it would be like having a CASE statement with the data.table, but I can't figure it out...

Thank you!

Comment: The `by` does not seem necessary for creation of that flag. Maybe you mean to use `any` somewhere?

Comment: I know it's a data.table related question but here is the dplyr way in case someone want : `dt %>%  group_by(DATE) %>% 
  filter(EVENT == "K" | !all(c("A", "K") %in% EVENT))`

Comment: I guess I oversimplified the example but I do need the 'by' for my data... I think what I actually need it's some combination with 'all' and 'any' as I indicated in the comment to the answer below... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dt[, flag := all(c('A', 'K') %in% EVENT), by = DATE]
dt
#   ID      DATE EVENT  flag
#1:  1 01-Jan-97     A  TRUE
#2:  1 01-Jan-97     K  TRUE
#3:  2 03-Jan-03     A FALSE
#4:  3 04-Jan-03     K FALSE
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, and amazingly quick! Thank you! Didn't think about the 'all' function. I'll accept the answer cause with the example I gave it's perfect but can I ask you what would you do if you had for instance A1, A2, K1, K2 and if any of the K was present, then I'd flag with TRUE? all(any(A1,A2),any(K1,K2)), maybe?

Comment: yes, smth like that should work, iiuc: `any(c('A1', 'A2') %in% EVENT) && any(c('K1', 'K2') %in% EVENT)`